# break not work while looping with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I'm looping over an array using a "for" loop.
I need to go through the loop at 2 second intervals.
Need to stop the loop if condition is met.
but I can't stop the loop because it has "setTimeout".

```js
let selects = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for (let j =0; j < selects.length; j++) {
    task(j);
    if (j===5) { break; }
}

function task(i) {
    let tasker = setTimeout(function() {
      
      console.log("loop " + i)
        
    }, 2000 * i);
}
```

Comment: You should be using `j==5` or `j===5`, single `=` is for assignment, and in your case evaluates to `5` which is always truthy

Comment: You're probably better off running your loop until `j <= 5` instead of `j < selects.length`, or using `setInterval()`.

Comment: With your new edit it's unclear what you're asking exactly. The loop now stops at 5, is this not what you're after, and what do you expect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to `j`, You need to use `===` or `==` instead of `=`

```
for (let j =0; j < selects.length; j++) {
    task(j);
    if (j === 5) { break; }
}
```